# BigQuery Transfer jobs from S3 stuck pending on first step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have several BigQuery Transfer jobs scheduled to load data from S3 every day. We set them up using web UI. They ran fine tonight at 3am UTC but now they are stuck pending, both when manually triggered and when scheduled. We have made no changes in either AWS or Google Cloud since the last time they ran.

Looking at the logs in the user interface, it's stuck on the first step: `Dispatched run to data source with id *****`

We have tried to create a new Transfer to another S3 bucket but it has the same problem. We have double checked all access keys and user permissions.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

[Transfer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvClo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Things started to work again. Perhaps a momentarily hiccup.

Comment: It seems that this is happening again today. All the transfers are stuck in the same status?

How long was it an issue?